# How to make that query with dates works with LINQPad

Tags: sql, linq, linqpad

I use LINQPad to access to an .SDF file and make some requests on it.

Everything is fine when I use that sql query :

`select * from SalesOrderDetail where OrderDate between '2019-08-30 18:00:00' and '2019-08-30 23:59:59'`

but, I'm unable to find the right query with `LINQ` to finally have a .linq file to save. Why ? because I need to use 'lprun' right after to export the result of the query.

For some reason, I'm not able to export the result with SQL query because the icon 'export to csv' didn't show up. May be that because I don't have the 'premium options'.

If someone could help, would appreciate.

Comment: What about using ExecuteQueryDynamic with your sql command?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement can be written in LINQ as follows:

```
SalesOrderDetails.Where(s => s.OrderDate >= new DateTime(2019, 8, 30, 18, 0, 0) && s.OrderDate < new DateTime(2019, 09, 01))
```

You can run SQL directly using `this.ExecuteQueryDynamic()` function.

LinqPad doesn't support exporting to CSV, only to Word, Excel and HTML. If you're using lprun there's no export functionality. You'd need to write the code as part of your LINQPad query to export the result to a CSV file.